How to make sure OpenAI object stays in its context in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC ajax calls
We have implemented OpenAI chatbot in our ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project. Installed OpenAI nuget package. It is working fine for one question, but observed than for next questions it is not staying in its own context. It is considering the input as a new question every time. Ex, If I ask, what is "What is ph formula in chemistry?", it gives the answer. If I ask convert this answer into Spanish language. It says I am here to tell you only about Chemistry. Expectation is, it should have converted the answer into given language. Could you please guide on this.
This is my controller's code:
 public class GenAIController : Controller
 {
     public PartialViewResult LoadSimulationsQuestions(string simulationName = "")
     {
         OpenAIHelper openAIHelper = new OpenAIHelper(simulationName);
         openAIHelper.ContentResponse = openAIHelper.GetQuestionsFromOpenAI();
         openAIHelper.SimulationName = simulationName;
         return PartialView("_SimulationsAIQA", openAIHelper);
     }

     [HttpGet]
     public JsonResult GetAnswerFromOpenAI(string simulationName = "", string userMessage = "")
     {
         OpenAIHelper openAIHelper = new OpenAIHelper(simulationName, false);
         openAIHelper.ContentResponse = openAIHelper.GetAnswerFromOpenAI(userMessage);
         return Json(openAIHelper.ContentResponse);
     }
 }

LoadSimulationsQuestions methods opens up the UI of Chatbot and GetAnswerFromOpenAI method is getting called from Ajax to send the user questions.
Helper class is
 public class OpenAIHelper
 {
     private string apiKey = "apiKey";
     private string model = "gpt-3.5-turbo"; // or "gpt-4" if you have access
     public List<ChatMessage> ChatMessages = new List<ChatMessage>();
     private SystemChatMessage systemChatMessage;
     private UserChatMessage userChatMessage;
     private ChatClient client;
     private string _SimulationName = "";
     private UseCase questionableUseCase;
     string[] Subjects = new string[3] { "PHYSICS", "CHEMISTRY", "BIOLOGY" };
     List<string> UserMessages = new List<string>();

     public string systemMessage = "Act as a Chemistry teacher. Don't reply to non educational or unrelated queries and avoid giving answers on Biology and Physics. Strictly make the answer under 500 characters.";
     public string userMessage;


     public OpenAIHelper(string simulationName)
     {
         string subjectName = "";
         string excludedSubject = "";
         string topics = "";
         _SimulationName = simulationName;
         systemChatMessage = new SystemChatMessage(systemMessage);
         ChatMessages.Add(systemChatMessage);
     }

         client = new(model: model, apiKey);
     }

     public string SimulationName { get; set; }
     public List<string> ContentResponse = new List<string>();

     public List<string> GetQuestionsFromOpenAI()
     {
         List<string> contentResponse = new List<string>();

         ChatCompletion completionResponse = client.CompleteChat(ChatMessages);

         if (completionResponse.Content != null && completionResponse.Content.Count > 0)
         {
             var results = completionResponse.Content[0].Text.Trim().Split('~');

             if (results.Count() == 1)
             {
                 results = completionResponse.Content[0].Text.Trim().Split('?');
             }
             for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
             {
                 contentResponse.Add(results[i]);
             }
         }

         return contentResponse;
     }

     public List<string> GetAnswerFromOpenAI(string userMessage)
     {
         userChatMessage = new UserChatMessage(userMessage);
         ChatMessages.Add(userChatMessage);

         List<string> contentResponse = new List<string>();

         ChatCompletion completionResponse = client.CompleteChat(ChatMessages);

         if (completionResponse.Content != null && completionResponse.Content.Count > 0)
         {
             contentResponse.Add(completionResponse.Content[0].Text.Trim());

         }
         return contentResponse;
     }
 }

Could you please guide, how can we make sure that OpenAI remains in same context for every ajax call?

https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/text-generation/conversations-and-context : While each text generation request is independent and stateless (unless you are using assistants), you can still implement multi-turn conversations by providing additional messages as parameters to your text generation request. [...] By using alternating user and assistant messages, you can capture the previous state of a conversation in one request to the model.
